# How to enable onClick event during TranslateAnimation in android studio?

Tags: android, animation, events, button, layout

I have a button that has a translate animation and moves around a certain layout.

When I click the button, I want to stop its animation and move it to another layout. the event for button.onClickListener() is not working and Toast message doesn't pop-up. What should I do?

Comment: nah! no error at all. It just the onClick() or onTouch() event is not working on current position of the button.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/H3iMvFK7

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for button click listener and then on it onClick method you can navigate to your next activity.

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v)
    {   
        //enter code here
    }
});
```